# Impossible to import koalas in scala notebook

Tags: scala, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-koalas

It seems basic but from what I see on databricks website, nothing works on my side

I have installed koalas package on my cluster
But when I try to import the package in my Scala notebook, I have issue.

```
command-3313152839336470:1: error: not found: value databricks
import databricks.koalas
```

If I do it in Python, everything works fine

[Details cluster & notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fb3Mc.jpg)

Thanks for your help
Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Koalas is a Python package, which mimics the Pandas (another Python package) interfaces. Currently no Scala version is published, even though the project may contain some Scala code. The goal of Koalas is to provide a drop-in replacement for Pandas, to make use of the distributed nature of Apache Spark. Since Pandas is only available on Python I don't expect a direct of port on this in Scala.

https://github.com/databricks/koalas

For Scala your best bet is to use the DataSet and DataFrame APIs of Spark:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html
https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/04/introducing-apache-spark-datasets.html

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have been confused by Spark Summit presentation which was mentioning Scala code :)